# Error : Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Offset not contained in string

Tags: php

Shows me Error :

> Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Offset not contained in string

Code is

```
function trimSearchURL($URL, $Pos, $end = '&')
{
    if ($Pos) {
         $nEndPos = strpos($URL, $end, $Pos);
        if ($nEndPos === false) {
            $URL = substr($URL, $Pos);
        } else {
            $URL = substr($URL, $Pos, $nEndPos - $Pos);
        }
    }
    return $URL;
}
```

Comment: Then do some basic debugging. What value is `Pos`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Pos appears to be larger than the string in $URL is long

```
$nEndPos = strpos($URL, $end, $Pos)
```